# Remove echo from function - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to accomplish an hard task. The task is removing a `echo` from a Yoast SEO file using the available WP hooks.

**class-frontend.php**

```
public function head() {
    global $wp_query;

    $old_wp_query = null;

    if ( ! $wp_query->is_main_query() ) {
        $old_wp_query = $wp_query;
        wp_reset_query();
    }

    /**
     * Action: 'wpseo_head' - Allow other plugins to output inside the Yoast SEO section of the head section.
     */
    do_action( 'wpseo_head' );

    echo '<!-- / ', $this->head_product_name(), ". -->\n\n"; // <-- remove this

    if ( ! empty( $old_wp_query ) ) {
        $GLOBALS['wp_query'] = $old_wp_query;
        unset( $old_wp_query );
    }

    return;
}
```

Is there a way to override this function and remove the `echo` using the available WP hooks? Or is there a better way to do this?

Many thanks.

Comment: Given that the `echo` command is not in a conditional execution path, there's obviously no way that invocation of a "hook" can avoid it being called (except a "hook" that entirely replaces the `head()` function altogether).

Comment: @eggyal Do you know some kind of way to replace this function with my own?

Comment: Can you explain how removing that line makes your life better? There may be other options.

Comment: @RST It would make my life more colorful again. It must be accomplished. No sleep otherwise. The `echo` an advertisement and it needs to go.

Comment: Why would you put every page through a filter just because of one line. Remove it from the original code and make a note of that in your website documentation so you can do it again after an upgrade.

Comment: @RST It's because this should be a plugin so you don't have to do this process over and over.

Comment: I would worry about the delay/overhead, but that is just me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There [is a post at wordpress.stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/remove-an-action-from-an-external-class) that indicates you can output buffer using the hooks `get_header` and `wp_head` to filter that out:

```
add_action('get_header', 'ad_ob_start');
add_action('wp_head', 'ad_ob_end_flush', 100);
function ad_ob_start() {
  ob_start('ad_filter_wp_head_output');
}
function ad_ob_end_flush() {
  ob_end_flush();
}
function ad_filter_wp_head_output($output) {
  if (defined('WPSEO_VERSION')) {
    $output = str_ireplace('<!-- / Yoast WordPress SEO plugin. -->', '', $output);
  }
  return $output;
}
```

That expects your `$this->head_product_name()` to be `/ Yoast WordPress SEO plugin.` so you may have to alter that...or if you want it to remove "anythere" there, you can change your replacement to something like this:

```
    $output = preg_replace('/<!-- .* -->/Us', '', $output);
```

But that will remove ALL comments, and it will be slower than the string replace.

Comment: That'll work, but there doesn't exist anything which can override the `head()` function within the Yoast class?

Comment: your request was to use available hooks and to remove the echo.  this does that.  you need a new question.